# What is the best way to print console logs using spring and apache tomcat? [2018]

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging

Currently I am facing issues while debugging errors and code using Apache tomcat console. Sometimes some logs appears, sometimes not.
I had searched enough about printing logs on console. They are not much easy understand/implement.

**Here I have `log4j.properties` of my code which does not print all logs and method in-out entries.**

```
log4j.rootCategory=debug,console
log4j.logger.com.demo.package=debug,console
log4j.additivity.com.demo.package=false

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8
#log4j.appender.console.threshold=warn

log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Which gives output logs as

```
2018-04-18 18:03:13,175 [main] INFO Demo - Log4j console appender configuration is successful !!
```

**Finally I want to know,**

**1. What is the best way to print INFO, error, warning logs in console or log file like**

2018-04-18 @ 18:03:13 INFO  -> methodName() -> Enter

2018-04-18 @ 18:03:14 INFO  -> methodName() -> Exit

**2. Is there any shortcut available in spring or java to print method names with Enter-Exit text as shown above ?** Otherwise I need to put Enter Exit in all methods.

Comment: Are you using Spring or Springboot ? AOP concepts will definitely help you.

Comment: Yes I am using Spring. I need to check about AOP. Thank you.

Comment: It is working fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1. What is the best way to print INFO, error, warning logs in console or log file**

For this issues, I would like to suggest you to use `log4j` with `aspects`. This will power up your console and visibility.

If you are using maven, Use this dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**You can create your own custom logs by changing your `log4j` configs.**

**log4j.properties**

```
#Root Logger Option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,myConsoleAppender,myAppender

## Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

## Redirect log messages to a log file 
log4j.appender.myAppender.File=${catalina.home}/logs/someFileName.log
log4j.appender.myAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.myAppender.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd@HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p - %m%n
```

You can even customize layout and Pattern of `myAppender` as you want. I had added code about to generate file with log.

**#2. Is there any shortcut available in spring or java to print method names with Enter-Exit text as shown above ?**

Yes, Java is too much huge. It have all possible solutions.

For this, You need to use `aspects` (You can search more about `AOP` i.e. Aspect Oriented Programming)

Use `slf4j` dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Follow below steps/code to put Enter-Exit method using single class.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:log4j.properties"})
public class LogginAspect {

    Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogginAspect.class);

    @Before("within(com.web.casemanager..*)")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("Inside "+ joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + " --> " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + " --> Enter");
    }

    @After("within(com.web.casemanager..*)")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("Inside "+ joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + " --> " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()  + " --> Exit");
    }
}
```

`@Before` and `@After` annotations will execute logger.info/ logger.error/ logger.warn on start and end of each method.

Hope so this will work for you.